# Australian work visa points for degree in chemical Engineering while working as a reservoir engineer

Tags: immigration, australia

I have a degree in chemical Engineering but I've been working as a reservoir engineer specifically in enhanced oil recovery. Can I get points for work experience for Australia immigration?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are talking about skilled worker visas....

You can if you find a 'Profession' to which your work in oil industry and your diploma would be considered relevant by the organization that is doing the assessment...

Assuming your diploma is Bachelor degree then I would look for 'Profession' that makes your diploma relevant as that is +15 points

To get same points from work experience you would [need to have 8+ years.](http://www.workpermit.com/immigration/australia/australian-skilled-immigration-points-requirements)...
And you would have to get references in specific format from all companies you have worked for, then get originals to Australian embassy and get them notarised (17GBP per page), only then they will be assepted by your assessor....

Ofc best would be to [find a skillsed that would cover both fronts](http://www.sbs.com.au/yourlanguage/hindi/en/article/2016/05/17/want-migrate-australia-2016-17-skilled-occupations-list-sol-announced)....